# Cordova build error, exit code 65 - Eddy Verbruggen Calendar Plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, calendar, llvm

I am trying to use the [Eddy Verbruggen Calendar Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin)

I created a new starter app (myApp), and ran the following instructions from the documentation:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

and run this command afterwards:

```
$ cordova build
```

From there I get the following Failure:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

CompileC build/myApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.build/Object-normal/i386/Calendar.o myApp/Plugins/nl.x-services.plugins.calendar/Calendar.m normal i386 objective-c  com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: /Users/stellar/desktop/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
at ChildProcess.whenDone    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova- lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Any guidance on how to proceed?

Best Regards,

Troy

Comment: Can you add some more of the output that was above `** BUILD FAILED **`

Comment: /Users/stellar/Desktop/EddyBuildFail.png  see if this comes across for you.

Comment: could you just copy the output from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be [an open issue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/172) on [the GitHub project](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) so you're not alone in facing this issue. Unfortunately, unless you attempt to isolate and identify the issue there isn't much you can do as it appears to be a problem with the plugin at the moment.

Fortunately, this plugin is a fairly popular one and there appears to be steady development on the repository so this is likely to be addressed eventually. If you do make progress or want to help out you should definitely [comment on the issue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/172).